# How to inherit from existing AMD js class in TypeScript compilng to AMD module?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, typescript

I did try the following:

```
class Child {
    public func() {
       alert("hello");
    }
    constructor() {
        Parent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
Child["prototype"] = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
Child["prototype"].constructor = Child;
```

but the instance of the Child class doesn't have func() method.

How to do inheritance from js class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General case

Just use `declare` in order to declare an existing class.

```
declare class Parent { // produces no JS code
    constructor(val);
}
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(val) {
        super(val);
    }
}
```

## Case of an external module (AMD)

The external module has to be described in a definition file `.d.ts`.

File `ContainerSurface.d.ts`:

```
declare class ContainerSurface {
  constructor(options);
}
export = ContainerSurface;
```

How to use it:

```
import ContainerSurface = require('ContainerSurface');

class Child extends ContainerSurface {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be great if this works!  However I get the following error: Extends clause of exported class 'Child' has or is using private name 'Parent'. Any ideas how to tell the compiler that Parent is just a global variable that is not private?

Comment: I'm trying to extend an AMD module https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Famous/famous/develop/src/surfaces/ContainerSurface.js.  And my Child class is also compiled with option to generate an AMD module. If I paste your example in typescriptlang.org playground it works, but it is not possible to enable AMD compilation there. If I compile your code, and say compile to AMD module, it gives the error if I add export=Child; at the end of the file.

Comment: AMD adds the file ContainerSurface.js to the require list, but the file does not compile into the actual required code, this doesn't work:-(

Comment: :( Maybe I missed something. I have no experience with AMD. However, my example compiles with the parameter `--module amd`. What is the actual required JS code?

Comment: You are right! It works! I had to add th path in the import statement for the .d.ts file so it mimics the real path where require (the AMD version) loads the actual AMD module from. I introduced in my source folder the structure, i.e.  famous/surfaces/ContainerSurface.d.ts.